# extracting indexes regex, with python

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I am trying to get certain strings and their indexes.But I always get only the index of the first one. Could anyone maybe tell me what am I doing wrong?
Thnks

here is what I have written:

```
import re 

f = open("topology_seq.txt")

strToSearch = ""
for line in f:
    strToSearch += line

patFinder = re.compile("I(L|p)")

findpattern = re.search(patFinder, strToSearch) 

findpattern1 = re.findall(patFinder, strToSearch)

for i in findpattern1:
    print(i), 
    print (findpattern.end())
```

Output:
L
143
p
143
L
143

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [finditer](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.finditer) method.

```
itr = re.finditer(patFinder, strToSearch)
indexes = [match.start(0) for match in itr]
```

> re.finditer(pattern, string, flags=0)
>
> Return an iterator yielding MatchObject instances over all non-overlapping >matches for the RE pattern in string